# How do i use custom fonts through JavaFx CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I've attempted adding a custom font to my program using CSS and i can't get it to work, is anyone able to help?

This is what i've got at the moment:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: walterturncoat;
    src: url("../resources/fonts/walterturncoat.ttf");
}

.label
{
    -fx-font-family: "Walter Turncoat";
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-size: 20pt;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #000000, 10, 0, 2, 2);
}
```

The url works as i used a similar path for an image (just /images/ instead of /fonts/) and i was able to get the font to work outside of CSS in the bulk of the program but i intend to be using it a lot so having it in CSS would be ideal.

Comment: If you have a regular project setup, then I would say that your url is wrong. Try "/fonts/walterturncoat.ttf"

Comment: Yeah didn't work, i use a similar path for an image that works fine so i don't think its the url ("../resources/images/Smoothies.jpg")